# Using multindex resample in pandas with zeros results in NaN

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, panel-data

I have a data frame that looks like this...

```
               name            datetime    value
1           Michael 2012-01-11 01:11:19     3999
3             Janus 2014-01-11 00:01:10        1
4             Janus 2014-01-11 01:12:29       81 
5             Janus 2014-01-11 01:11:19     8047
...             ...                 ...      ...
9001230  Excalibur1 2014-12-25 01:11:10        1
9001231  Excalibur1 2014-12-25 02:11:10        2
9001232  Excalibur1 2013-12-25 03:11:10        3
9001233  Excalibur1 2014-12-25 04:11:10        4
9001234  Excalibur1 2014-12-25 05:11:10      907
```

I want to find, for each name, how many the total value each day.

In days with no values listed, I want these days to still exist, and I want to fill zeros.

I can do the following, which seems to only sometimes zero fill:

```
df.set_index(["datetime"]).groupby("name").resample("D")["value"].sum()
name        datetime
Michael     2012-01-11     3999
Janus       2014-01-11     8129
            2014-10-12        0
            2014-10-13        0
            2014-10-14        0
                            ...  
Excalibur1  2014-12-21        0
            2014-12-22        1
            2014-12-23        0
            2014-12-24        0
            2014-12-25      917
```

Why is it /sometimes/ filling with zeros and what's the right way to rectangularize this so I have all dates summed and filled with zero where no records exist?

## Update

The index I would like is composed of...

```
index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
pd.date_range(
  df["datetime"].dt.date.min(),  
  df["datetime"].dt.date.max(), freq="D"),
sorted(df["name"].unique()
)
```

And dense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `resample`, but use the date in the `groupby`:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

df.groupby(['name', df['datetime'].dt.date]).sum()
```

Or, using [`pandas.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) for flexibility:

```
df.groupby(['name', pd.Grouper(key='datetime', freq='D')]).sum()
```

Output:

```
                       value
name       datetime         
Excalibur1 2013-12-25      3
           2014-12-25    914
Janus      2014-01-11   8129
Michael    2012-01-11   3999
```

##### rectangular shape and missing dates:

For a rectangular shape use:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['name', pd.Grouper(key='datetime', freq='D')])['value'].sum().unstack(level='name', fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
name        Excalibur1  Janus  Michael
datetime                              
2013-12-25           3      0        0
2014-12-25         914      0        0
2014-01-11           0   8129        0
2012-01-11           0      0     3999
```

And to add missing dates, `reindex`:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['name', pd.Grouper(key='datetime', freq='D')])['value'].sum().unstack(level='name', fill_value=0)
df2 = df2.reindex(pd.date_range(df['datetime'].dt.date.min(), df['datetime'].max()), fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
name        Excalibur1  Janus  Michael
2012-01-11           0      0     3999
2012-01-12           0      0        0
2012-01-13           0      0        0
2012-01-14           0      0        0
2012-01-15           0      0        0
...
```

Comment: This is great, thank you---I have too many observations in my "name" index to use a wide data frame.  Is it possible to keep it long rather than splaying them as columns and still maintain my zeros?

Comment: Sure, simply `unstack` the datetime level and `reindex` the columns instead. Or transpose the current final result.

Comment: Thanks.  But transpose would just put the names on the index and the dates on the column---by rectangular, I just mean all names and all dates are in the multiindex, but still long like your first output, not wide like your last output.

Comment: I have updated the question to show the multindex.

Comment: @Mittenchops I can't check now (on the phone), but you can skip the unstack part and reindex the long format. I'm not sure where you're stuck.

Comment: That reindex does not work without the unstack: `ValueError: cannot include dtype 'M' in a buffer`